# Import module from node-modules in asp.net core mvc project

Tags: node.js, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bpmn.io

I'm building a BPMN modeler using the [BPMN-Js](https://github.com/bpmn-io) package using asp.net core mvc, I need to import this module

```js
import BpmnModeler from 'bpmn-js/lib/Modeler';
```

I set up the package.json file in asp.net and added the node-modules folder in UseStaticFiles

Now I can't figure out how to import BpmnModeler in script, I read about bundling but it's all new to me, a little help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @hpPh, where is your js file location? How do you configure the `node-modules` folder in `UseStaticFiles`? Is there any error message in browser when you import the module?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to create a **webpack.config.js** file give as input the js file with the imports from node-modules and as output the resulting file which is bundle.js and I simply call this bundle from my html.